# Many to many in laravel not working

Tags: database, laravel-5.4, eloquent

My User model code is

```
public function companies()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company');
}
```

My companies table has below field

```
id
company_name
company_address
company_phone
created_at
updated_at
```

and My company_user table has below field

```
user_id
company_id
created_at
updated_a
```

My Company model has below code

```
public function users()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

When I call

```
$user=Auth::user()->companies;
```

It shows nothing. But My company has data. also, my company_user table has appropriate data. What is the problem

Comment: Check the output of `Auth::user()` on its own. Is it returning a valid user? and are you sure the user in the database has companies?

Comment: thnx. I have checked, Auth::user returns valid users. And Also in company_user there is data with this user id.
Even I have made new Model,Migrate,Controller with Bed,bed_table,bed_user_table,BedController. But not working. It can save in bed table. But attach not working. Giving erring undefined

Comment: Works well with== return User::find(1);
Works well with== return Bed::all(); 
Not Works  with== return User::find(1)->beds;